# Kendo Date Picker:Disable Dates

Tags: php, kendo-ui

I am working with Kendo date picker.I am trying to disable the dates before 2000-01-01. Is it possible with Kendo date picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set the `min` value of the date picker:

```
// set the min date to Jan 1st, 2011
$("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    min: new Date(2000, 0, 1),
    // other config options
});
```